# iOS/Objective-C(Swift)でWKWebViewの初期表示が遅い原因は？( ガワネイティブ、ハイブリッド)

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

## 質問

1. WKWebViewは、『生成⇒ロード⇒表示開始⇒表示完了』で数秒かかる処理はありますか？（約1～2.5秒）
2. WKWebViewは、『生成～表示～破棄』を繰り返す場合、初回生成のWKWebViewを再利用が『表示速度が速く・適切な方法』ですか？
3. ネット上で、WKWebViewの生成が遅い／WKWebViewのページロードが遅い等の情報がない。生成もロードも体感で一瞬が普通ですか？
   ※表示するページの複雑さ・サイズに影響されるが

## 補足

### 条件・状態

- iOSのWKWebViewを使用した「ガワネイティブ／ハイブリッド」のアプリ開発。
- Objective-C(Swift)でWKWebViewを使用。
- ネイティブのボタンタップで、WKWebViewでHTML(WEBページ)を表示／クローズ。
- Yahooページ／"Hellow World!!"シンプルページ の表示速度を確認。
- 表示完了までに1.?秒～2.5秒かかる。
- 同じURLでも『アプリの起動繰り返し／操作繰り返し』で表示速度（表示時間）は毎回バラつく。
- どのURLでも表示速度（表示時間）がバラつく。
- 表示のされかたは、真っ白な状態の上記時間後、パッと瞬間で表示され読み込んだ部分から表示されない。
- アプリ内で、アプリ画面の画面遷移は一瞬でできており、WKWebViewの表示だけ1.?秒～2.5秒くらいかかる。

### 上記から、テストアプリ開発その１『ブラウザ アプリ』

- ブラウザアプリを作った。
- URLを入力 ⇒ 表示ボタンタップ ⇒ 一瞬でHTMLページが表示される。
- その状態で何度やっても一瞬で表示される。
  ※一瞬とは目視で測定不可能なほど速いこと。

### 上記から、予想。

- WKWebViewは生成に1.?秒～2.5秒の時間がかかるのでは？
  ※時間にバラつきがある理由はライブラリ内部で生成時に何かが？

### 上記から、テストアプリ開発その２『WKWebView再利用 アプリ』

- 生成したWKWebViewを再利用する為、生成処理は初回のみ。
- 初回のみ1.?秒～2.5秒の時間がかかるようになった。
- 二回目以降の表示は一瞬。＝ブラウザと同じ速度。

### 上記から、疑問。

- WKWebViewの生成・表示が遅いという情報が見つからない理由は？
  （表示は速いとの情報多数あり。生成が速いや遅いとの情報なし。）
- WKWebViewのプログラム／使用方法が違っている場合、生成／表示に『1.?秒～2.5秒の時間がかかる』が『正常に表示される』といったケースもあるのか？

Comment: 質問を詳しく記載することは良い事ですが短くするように心がけてください。例えば質問上でノイズとなるような「※この質問が～」や「▼ご質問させていただきます。～」など、質問に関係ないことは不要です。また質問文の前後で「ご質問１～」と同じことを記載しているのも1つでいいかと。質問が長いと現状を把握されづらい傾向にあり回答がつきづらいです。

Comment: 承知しました。  修正します。

Comment: 初期表示が遅い事例を検出。【WKWebViewリファレンンス日本語訳】https://qiita.com/shunyooo/items/d03a714af4dadd0727a6        【WKWebView】https://www.terrasky.co.jp/blog/2015/150311_001405.php

Comment: 初期表示が遅い事例をさらに検出（アニメーションGIF） ⇒ 
参考３）https://anz-note.ghost.io/2018/03/14/2212/
参考４）https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445988/wkwebview-content-jumping-on-load ※注：ページジャンプさせている為ロードに時間がかかっている可能性あり。
参考５）https://www.jianshu.com/p/3af0255a67ce
参考６）https://techa1008.com/img/rocket-note/20171223/022.gif ※WKWebViewの再利用と新規作成時の両方の速度が見れる。
参考７）https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856616/wkwebview-action-sheet-dismisses-the-presenting-view-controller-after-being-dism

Comment: 自己のまとめはコメントではなく自己回答という形で投稿してください。自己回答を行うと数日後に承認でき、承認することで質問が解決済みになります。

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。

## 本件の調査・質問の結果

WKWebViewの生成には数秒かかる(例：1.5～2.5秒 ※タイミング、端末により時間は異なる)。

## 根拠・理由

１．"生成に時間はかからない／時間がかかる"や"時間がかかるのは仕様"、"生成を速くする方法／遅い原因"などの文章や情報が見つからず決定的な判断はできないですが。
２．本検証用にテストアプリを別途作成したが、やはり生成が遅い。
３．ネット上でSwiftやObjective-C、色々な国の人達の開発アプリの動作動画からも『生成は数秒かかる』ことがわかる(一部予測を含む)。
４．単なる補足ですが。Appleに問い合わせしていましたが、『"回答できない"という回答』でした。※注：Appleへの問合せ自体が問題で回答をもらえなかった可能性あり。